Are there a cipher function $E_k$ and a hash function $H$ commutative on composition (permutable)?
Two functions $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are commutative on composition, or permutable, if $f(g(x))=g(f(x))$.
Given a file $f$, is there a cipher function $E_k$ and a hash function $H$ with the property: $H(E_k(f))=E_k(H(f))$, i.e. the hash of file $f$ encrypted is the same of encrypt the hash of $f$.
EDIT: Context added
Why I want to find those functions? To build trustless file transfer protocol (proof of availability):
Alice and bob agree on $d = H(f)$.
1 - Alice commits $K$.
2 - Alice encrypts $f$ obtaining $f'=E_k(f)$, sends $f'$ to Bob and informs $d'=H(f')$.
3 - Bob calculates the hash $d'=H(f')$ and confirms he received $f'$ with digest $d'$.
4 - If Alice's $d'$ is the same reported by Bob, Alice reveals $K$.
5 - A third party can verify that $d'=E_k(d)$ (note that a third party do not must have the file $f$ or $f'$).
6 - Bob have access to $K$ and can decrypts his file.

Yes, the identity permutation..

You are totally correct, but the identity permutation is trivial and can not be considered a cipher function, for practical situations.

Hint: take a look at the pre-image resistance properties of cryptographically secure hash functions. Note that I don't think that the identity function would be a good example in this case as we'd want the function to be for any $k$ and there is no configuration option for a $k$ as parameter of the hash.

Are "files" $f$ of arbitrarily variable size? If so, must $H(f)$ be of fixed size? What security properties are asked for $E_k$ and $H$?

$f$ are arbitrary size files, $H(f)$ must be of fixed size and must be relatively short to be used as ID (e.g. 256), $E_k$ and $H$ are intended to be used as cipher and hash in practical situations and must have all security properties. I edited the question  adding context.

Instead of your protocol, could you just define your need properly?

$H(E_k(f))=E_k(H(f))$. Note that if do not exist $E_k$ and $H$ with this property, this is also a valuable answer. I am not sure if they exist...

By considering what happens when we twice encrypt then hash the same message, we see that if $H$ is collision-resistant, then $E_k$ needs to be deterministic. Thus the cipher $E$ can't be semantically secure. So some corners must be cut on "must have all security properties".

I don't understand the idea of the scheme. $d'$ acts like a checksum for $f'$, and if the checksum matches then Bob gets access to $K$. Why is the third party needed? And why is the encryption needed if the key is published right after the transfer?

The point is that the third party can be sure that Alice sent the correct file $f$ whose hash is $d$ to Bob, and Bob confirmed that he received this exactly file before $K$ is revealed. The third party may be a treasurer that transfer funds from Bob to Alice as payment for the file transfer.

That doesn't sound trustless. If Bob gets access to $K$ before payment is made, then Alice needs to trust Bob to provide payment. If Bob does not receive $K$ until after payment is made, then Bob trusts the third party that they'll share $K$ with Bob once the payment is made, and Alice trusts that the third party does not share $K$ until after payment. Both Alice and Bob have to place trust in the same third party at the very least.

The logic is: Alice sends to Bob the file $f'$, Bob confirm he received, Alice revel $K$ and Bob can decrypt its file $f'$ to get $f$. If Alice and Bob follow the protocol and send all info to the third part, then the third part can be sure Alice sent the corret file that was received by Bob just by comparing  $d'$ with $E_k(d)$ (the third part do not kwon the file). Alice and Bob must trust that the third part will proceed with the payment, it can be a bank that transfer between acconts, for instance. I see no fail in the protocol logic.

@n-l-i Imagine the third part is a smart contract and Bob and Alice share all info in the contract, it should make sense now.
